# Chrome extension: detect create window event from background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

**Task:** I am opening chrome(with my extension installed) with selenium webdriver in python. I want to attach a listener when selenium opens the window of chrome.

**Already Tried:** I have already tried `chrome.windows.onCreated` event in background of my extension, but it is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a work around of it. May be helpful for others aswell. First, `chrome.windows.onCreated` will fire only if a new window is created from current window. Since I wanted to run some logic when selenium creates a fresh window therefore I put the code in a **myFunction** and call that function directly in **background** page. As a fresh chrome is created by a code in **background** page executes once and calls **myfunction**.